# JTRevealSideBar dismiss sidebar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sidebar

I have implemented the JTRevelSideBar into my project, and it's working quite well, but I have been trying to figure out if it was possible to do something like with the Facebook app, where if the user presses the main viewcontroller, while the sidebar is revealed, the sidebar should be dismissed. Do anybody know this is possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never having used it before, I will say: *probably*.

Though, the github page for the pod you mention says that it's no longer being supported due to its use being discouraged at the WWDC14. Though, one of the alternatives that JT mentions is PKRevealController2 and seems to be fairly simple to use.

Though the reason I bring it up at all is that usually devs will give you some hint as to how to do what you are asking for in one of the project's main header files. For example in [PKRevealController.h](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/blob/master/Source/PKRevealController/PKRevealController.h) it lists the property

```
/// Whether to use the front view's entire visible area to allow pan based reveal.
    @property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL recognizesPanningOnFrontView;
```

Which is exactly what you'd want to set as `YES` in your project. I would recommend to take a look at the header files in the JTRevealSideBar pod to see if there is something similar.

Now, I have used [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) before (it's pretty great!) and similarly it has a **MMCloseDrawerGestureMode** which can be set to **MMCloseDrawerGestureModeBezelPanningCenterView** (The user can close the drawer by starting a pan anywhere within the bezel of the center view.)

So you see, you'll just have to do a little digging. Otherwise you'll need to implement a pan gesture recognizer... but I can't really say for sure where you'll be putting it in your particular implementation.